# Javascript regex test() error: Object has no method 'test'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, testing

I cant get the javascript `test()` method to work, I keep getting an error, this regular expression is working fine when using the `match()` function.

This is my JS:

```
reg="^(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)(?:/)(?:watch?v=)?([^&]+)";

ytl=$('#yt').val();    //this is just an input value
if(reg.test(ytl)){
    alert('works');
}
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
Object ^(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)(?:/)(?:watch?v=)?([^&]+) 
has no method 'test'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `test` method is defined on [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) objects. Try this:

```
var reg = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)(?:\/)(?:watch?v=)?([^&]+)/;
```

Or this:

```
var reg = RegExp("^(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)(?:/)(?:watch?v=)?([^&]+)");
```

Comment: Interesting, so much to learn with JavaScript, when I have no issues with PHP, seems so much more finicky, just my inexperience however. That works perfectly, thanks.